# programmatically alter project settings

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I have an old MFC solution with 120 projects in it.
Now Im trying to compile it with VisualC 2017 but every project emits the error:

> cannot open file mfc140d.lib

Opening project properties, change the platform toolset to VS2017 141 and the the language version to C++17 fixes it.
But it will take a looooong time to do this for 120 projects and then the same for release build. Which are the settings in the project files that I can change programatically to set these two options? I sure cant find them

Comment: You only need to click 120 times if you select "All configurations" instead of doing it separately for "Release" and "Debug". Otherwise, do the changement for one project, look what has changed in the .vcxproj file and then do a find/replace with your favorite text editor.

Comment: the key thing here was that I assumed it was the .vcproj file and not the .vcxproj file, damn

Comment: Use [property pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/ide/working-with-project-properties#property-pages). Alternatively, switch to a programmable build system, like CMake. Everyone hates it (and that includes me), but there is not an alternative to manage complex build systems. Or, slightly paraphrasing Stroustrup: There are only 2 types of build systems: Those, that everybody complains about, and those, that nobody uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a python script that adds stdcpp17 and v141 to the vcxproj file if non existing. Maybe somebody finds a use for it:

```
def get_all_files(basedir):
    for root, subfolders, files in os.walk(basedir):
        for file in os.listdir(root):
            yield root, file

def all_lines_from_file(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as fd:
        for line in fd.readlines():
            yield line

def update_VCXPROJ():
    standard = '<LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>'
    toolset = '<PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>'
    add1 = '<CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>'
    add2 = '<DebugInformationFormat>'

    for root, file in get_all_files('c:/projects/6thcycle/sources/'):
        if not file.lower().endswith('.vcxproj'):
            continue

        thisfile = ''
        for line in all_lines_from_file('{0}/{1}'.format(root, file)):
            if toolset in line or standard in line:
                continue

            if add1 in line:
                line += '    {0}\n'.format(toolset)
            elif add2 in line:
                line += '      {0}\n'.format(standard)

            thisfile += line

        with open('{0}/{1}'.format(root, file), 'w') as fd:
            fd.write(thisfile)    

update_VCXPROJ()
```